# nodownload video attribute in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, video

I can use the nodownload video attribute on a VF page.  Can't seem to get it to work on component.  Is there a way to get nodownload attribute to work?

```
<aura:component>
<aura:html tag="div">
    <video width="640" height="480" poster="{!$Resource.NIIMBL_Logo}" controls="true" controlsList="nodownload" >
        <source src="/resource/video" type="video/mp4"  />
    </video>
</aura:html>
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same problem

Comment: By not working do you mean it just doesn't appear in the rendered markup? Is there a way you could add it via JS after rendering?

Comment: Matt - It is not appearing in the rendered markup.  I haven't looked into JS yet.

Comment: I did not find a way to do it with a lightning component.  I use Visualforce components to display my videos.

Answer (score 0):

we found the solution for it! yes salesforce is escaping some attributes from video tag after loading the page.

it works if we do it like below:

```
    <aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="vidVal" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
    
    <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.vidVal}"> </aura:unescapedHtml>
    
    <aura:component/>

 doInit : function(component,event){

            var vid = component.get("v.slide.mediaUrl");


            var ele = '<video aura:id="videoRenderer" disablePictureInPicture="true" controls="Play,Pause" controlsList="nodownload"> <source src="'+vid+'" type="video/mp4"> </source>Browser dont support Videos.</video> '
            component.set("v.vidVal" , ele);

            }
            
    }
```